# Weird ID variables in ASPX website

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server

I am hoping to take data from an ASPX site and use it on my own. I am a PHP developer and am used to having nice ID variables posted back to the server. Then I can just form the url with the ID I want, parse the html and I am good to go.

The ID variable for this site was :33ED6E44C6F8D71AA7F00641C0650842 but now it is 276D4D104D1E4E342BAF6C7DC20DCB6A. I thought it was the GUID from the database but can it be if it is changing? Perhaps it is hashed or encrypted using the session_State variable (according to a developer i asked)?

Does anyone have any ideas on how this ID variable works? I am not going to post the website but was hoping that ID variable would be enough to learn more. I know that isn't much information but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

EDIT** this is the source of the form

```
<body>

<form name="form1" method="post" action="details.aspx?id=2E8ECBC20B98DDF6033848ACD889A9F0&amp;lang=fr" id="form1">
```

Comment: Do you mean the server side `ID` parameter, which gets to `<HTML ID=/>` ?

Comment: Those ID's do appear to be GUID's, since they are 32-character hex codes.  But it could be some sort of a session ID instead to hide the actual request.  Basically you are saying, you access the exact same data element over and over and getting different url's, i.e., `Details.aspx?ID=276D4D104D1E4E342BAF6C7DC20DCB6A`?

Comment: Exactly however it doesn't change every time. Usually it changes after a day or so which is what made me think it is related to the session

Answer (score 1):

Here are some information about the `ID` tag you might find useful: 
http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/master-pages/control-id-naming-in-content-pages-cs

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, a session is considered active as long as requests continue to be made with the same SessionID value. If the time between requests for a particular session exceeds the specified time-out value in minutes, the session is considered expired. Requests made with an expired SessionID value result in a new session and a new ID. 
This ID is actually a cryptographically unique ID, but I'm not sure if it is hashed or encrypted using the session_State variable.

**EDIT**:

According to your last question

> Do you know if there is any common way to do this? Any sort of built in .net hashing function?

Well, SessionID's are created in the **SessionStateModule**. To extend the session
state under ASP.NET you will need to write *your own HTTP module* and replace
the SessionStateModule in the machine.config. The SessionStateModule is
the module which provides all the session state functionality for ASP.NET.
The SessionStateModule is sealed so you cannot extend it. Perhaps they are
trying to tell us something? You can replace it; however, there is'nt any
documentation other than how to create a HTTP module to help you accomplish
this task. Unless you have a really really good argument for rolling your
own sessionid, I would stick with what has been provided for you.

Comment: Do you know if there is any common way to do this? Any sort of built in .net hashing function?